# How to find the radius of an irregular circle using OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, geometry

How can I estimate the radius of an irregular circle I have detected? I have used `findContours()` to find where the circles are and used `moments()` to find the centre of mass. I now just need the radius of the circle so I can estimate it's volume.

For finding contours I have used the following code:

```
findContours(Closed_Image, Contours, Hierarchy, 
             CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0,0) );
```

For finding the centre of mass I have used the following code:

```
vector<Moments> mu(Contours.size() );
b = 0;
for(b = 0; b < Contours.size(); b++)
{
    mu[b] = moments(Contours[b], true);
}

vector<Point2f> mc(Contours.size() );
c = 0;
for(c = 0; c < Contours.size(); c++)
{
    mc[c] = Point2f(mu[c].m10/mu[c].m00, mu[c].m01/mu[c].m00);
    cout << "Contours Centre = " << mc[c] << endl;
}
```

I'm guessing that I need to use the contour points stored in `Contours` but the shape isn't a perfect circle so the distance between each point in the contour and its centre of mass would be different. Is this just a matter of averaging the distance between the centre of mass and each point in the contour (average distance = radius)? If so, how can I actually implement it (I'm not sure how to access data in `vector<vector<Point> > Contours;`). Otherwise, how would I be able to achieve estimating the radius?

[(Click here for the image I am working with)](http://postimg.org/image/pvbkhwg9p/)

Centre of mass is as follows: `[424.081, 13.4634], [291.159, 10.4545], [157.833, 10.4286], [24.5198, 8.09127]`

Comment: `r = sqrt(area / pi)`, count/calculate the number of the pixels which are considered part of the circle.

Comment: Thanks @H2CO3, I'm planning on calculating the area using `contourArea()` but the contour itself is only the edges of the circle (It looks filled in the image because I have used `drawContours()` and set `thickness` parameter to `-1`). Will this make a difference? ie. will the `contourArea()` only calculate the contour points or will it calculate the contour interiors as well?

Comment: @userXXX I've never used OpenCV, but I'm sure 1. that's in the documentation, 2. if it really calculates the area, it wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: "I now just need the radius of the circle so I can estimate it's volume.* -- don't you mean *area*?